# Plugin management on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

I am really new to vim and have been trying to use it more over the past months. Issue is I cannot get the plugins to work, I have followed the steps on vim plug github and some other sites.

I am on windows and when I use the `:set path` in vim itself it shows the vim directory but appending to it is a folder called `vimfiles`, is this just a general name for all associated files?

I added the plug lines to my `_vimrc` but when I run `:PlugInstall` it throws a error saying it's not a command. Is there any up to date info on windows installations ? This feels like a easy issue but I cannot figure it out and without syntax higlighting or anything it is kind of rough.

What I want to know is:

- where to put files for vim plug?
- why vim plug is not loading?
- Why do I have 3 auto load folders spread over separate folders?

Comment: There is a difference between `:set path` and `:set runtimepath`, just FYI. Also, if you’re wondering about option-related stuff, `:help` is a goldmine

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned out the installation and pulled the zip of vim-plug. Extracted the files into the autoload folder in vim82. Before I used the powershell solution.

After that I made a custom plugin folder and gave it read/write permission.
Now it seems to work. Unsure what the issue was but these are the things that I changed. Also I should have mentioned that I am using vim-plug.

Answer (score -1):

`:PluginInstall` is the install command for Vundle. If it does not work Vundle is not installed correctly.

[Installation Instructions](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start)

Comment: Hmm it seems vim plug uses this too, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
Plug and vundle do the same thing right? Or do I need vundle for plug?

Comment: The OP is talking about **Plug**Install (from vim-plug), not **Plugin**Install (from Vundle.) Vundle is not really relevant here, it's not involved, at all.

Comment: @filbranden Oh!

Comment: Please delete your answer. You have completely misread the question and are trying to correct OP when you are the one making a mistake, thus adding complete noise to this thread by creating a false (not even a comment!!) answer which only misleads people even more. Respect the community and delete your answer.